# Querying normalized table with multiple rows (sales funnel) events per customer

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a sales funnel dataset and each row represents a move through the funnel. As there are quite a few ways a potential customer can move through the funnel (and go backwards), I wasn't planning on flattening/denormalizing the table. How can I for example calculate "how many customers have churned and reactivated"?

```
customer | opp_id | status_old | status_new | current_opp_status | status_change_date
cust_8   | 22     | confirmed  | paying     | paying             | 2020-01-01
cust_9   | 23     | confirmed  | paying     | churned            | 2020-01-03
cust_9   | 23     | paying     | churned    | churned            | 2020-01-08
cust_12  | 24     | confirmed  | paying     | churned            | 2020-01-01
cust_12  | 24     | paying     | churned    | churned            | 2020-03-21
cust_12  | 28     | confirmed  | paying     | paying             | 2020-04-03
cust_13  | 30     | confirmed  | paying     | paying             | 2020-02-03
...      | ...    | ...        | ...        | ...                | ...
```

In the above case, I'd like to essentially identify **cust_12**, as they churned but then came back as a paying customer, with a new opportunity id, but am even struggling with where to start. Any suggestions?

Comment: What if you add another row for cust_12 with churned? Would this customer be in the results? Also is there a column defining the order of the rows?

Comment: So no, that customer cust_12, if churned again, should not be included. There was a column with **status_change_date** that is available - I just edited the table. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use aggregation:

```
select customer
from t
group by customer
having min(case when status_new = 'churned' then status_change_date end) <
       max(case when status_new = 'paying' then status_change_date end);
```

Actually, given your data, a simple `where` might be sufficient:

select t.*
from t
where status_new = 'paying' and status_old = 'churned'